# Python Psycopg2 RealDictCursor returns nondeterministic results

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a postgresql database and am querying it in python with psycopg2. If I repeat the same query multiple times under seemingly the same conditions, I sometimes get unexpected results. Here are the details:

I'm using psycopg2 and RealDictCursor:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor 

self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
            host="db",
            database=os.environ["DB_NAME"],
            user=os.environ["DB_USER"],
            password=os.environ["DOCKERDBPASS"],
        )
self.cur = self.conn.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
```

My table that I want to query looks like this:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ct_session(
        id_nb SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        bk INT NOT NULL,
        status VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        created_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
        closed_on TIMESTAMP NULL,
        CONSTRAINT fk_bk FOREIGN KEY(bk) REFERENCES app_user(django_id)
    );
```

Now this is the actual query:

```
query = """
SELECT
    id_nb
FROM ct_session
WHERE status = 'open'
;
"""

self.cur.execute(query)
result = self.cur.fetchone()
print("====DEBUG====", result)
if result:
    return result["id_nb"]
else:
    return None
```

Most of the time the printed debug line is as expected:

```
====DEBUG==== RealDictRow([('id_nb', 1)])
```

However, sometimes I get an unexpected:

```
====DEBUG==== RealDictRow([('status', 1)])
```

or

```
====DEBUG==== RealDictRow([(<class 'psycopg2.extras.RealDictRow'>, ['id', 'user', 'status']), ('id', 1)])
```

This is happening in a test environment with multiple different requests per second. Is there any explanation for this behavior? Might this be related to multiple different queries being processed more or less simultaneously?

Comment: Answers: no and no. The bug is somewhere else, I cannot see it in your question.

Comment: how could I go about debugging this? this is the only line of code that prints "====DEBUG====", and it immediately follows after executing the query. I see no possibility for "result" to be anything else than the result of this query

Comment: this does not happen if I run the same query on DBeaver

Comment: it appears to only happen if my Django app is running in debug mode. Not sure if related.

Comment: The code shown is so simple that a bug couldn't take care of hiding in it, IMO. However, it's only a part of a method, I'd analyze the whole class. And Django's debug mode might be the right lead.

Comment: SQL data is unordered by default so a `SELECT` without an `ORDER BY` will be nondeterministic. If you want a repeatable solution then add an `ORDER BY` that achieves that.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you for clarifying that. In this case, the nondeterministic part is not the order of results but rather the column itself. In one case it returns 'id_nb', in another 'status'

Comment: Aah, sorry I missed that. Then the issue is that either 1) The value of `query` is changing or 2) `self.cur.fetchone()` is fetching from a different cursor. What test mechanism are you using?